# debug jquery elastislide plugin error

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the elastislide plugin found at http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/12/elastislide-responsive-carousel/ . Now it works fine except when I try to manually set the current image.

My code:

```
var wdornot_carousel = $("#wdornot_carousel").elastislide({
...
...
});
wdornot_carousel.setCurrent(5);
```

With this I get the error: `TypeError: this.$carousel is undefined on line 655`

So inside the js, on line `651`, that is just a bit before that error, I did `console.log(this);`, which gave me an object which does have a $carousel property referencing a jquery object...so why is this.$carousel being seen as undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other javascript frameworks such as Prototype included.
Prototype also uses the $ and can cause conflicts like this.

You can use both libraries safely by using the noConflict function

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
// Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Check out the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/